# Footnote in Caption of Figure on latex

Tags: latex

Although i have tried many code of a footnote in a caption of a figure , it doesn't work , really , where is the problem here

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\pagenumbering{Roman}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document} 
              
\begin{figure}
      \centering                        
      \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth{images/frog.jpg}
      \caption[frog]{frog \footnotemark }
      \label{fig:pic1}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{frog}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [mre] that shows us which documentclass and packages you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

- you can't have the `\makenomenclature` macro in your code with a package which defines it, e.g. `nomencl`
- the `]` after the optional argument of your graphic is missing

With the split between `\footnotetext` and `\footnotemark` there is always the risk that the floating figure and the footnote will end up on different pages. You can lessen the risk by using `[htbp]` as floating specifier for your figure, this way you at least allowed the figure to be placed where the footnote is.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\makenomenclature

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\pagenumbering{Roman}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document} 
              
\begin{figure}[htpb]
      \centering                        
      \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
      \caption[frog]{frog \footnotemark }
      \label{fig:pic1}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{frog}

\end{document}
```

[image]